# How to scale a second row to 100% height with google maps api?

Tags: html, google-maps, css

I am trying to set a 2 row scaffold for a site, the first row a fixed height navbar and the second a google map API that takes the remainder of the screen height.

I have the following code, but when I offset the map div, it scrolls the content. Anybody know how to fix this?

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.ps-map
{
top:70px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
z-index:-100;
}

.ps-nav
{
top:0px;
height:50px;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
background:blue;
z-index:100;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ps-map" id="ps-map-id">
</div>

  <div class="ps-nav">
  Nav
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ps-map
{
    top:70px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-100;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```